# Format of Event logs structure in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I am running a simple contract in remix. I have an event in my contract which will be emitted just to check values of stateVariables.

```
contract stateVariable{
uint stateVariable1=10;
uint stateVariable2=20;
uint stateVariable3=30;
event log(uint stateVariable);
function display() public
{
   //emit log(stateVariable1,stateVariable2,stateVariable3); 
   emit log(stateVariable1); 
   emit log(stateVariable2); 
   emit log(stateVariable3); 
}
```

}

My question is about the format of log emitted in Remix. Why below log message contains "0" :"10" ? Is it something which shows the arguments number and it's value ?

> > {
> >
> > "from": "0x0dcd2f752394c41875e259e00bb44fd505297caf",
> >          "topic": >> 
> >     "0xf82c50f1848136e6c140b186ea0c768b7deda5efffe42c25e96336a90b26c744",
> >          "event": "log",
> >          "args": {
> >              **"0": "10",**
> >              "stateVariable": "10",
> >              "length": 1
> >          }
> >      },

When i tried to display all three stateVariables it shows below :

> "args": {
>
> > ```
> >      **"0": "10",
> >      "1": "20",
> >      "2": "30",**
> >      "stateVariable1": "10",
> >      "stateVariable2": "20",
> >      "stateVariable3": "30",
> >      "length": 3
> >   }
> > ```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like remix is expanding the args object with event parameter indexes (`"0" : ..., "1": ..., ...`) and parameter count (`"length"`). When using web3 directly you would only see `"args": { "stateVariable": "10" }`. See https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events-return for details.

Answer (score 0):

In software and programming, indexes generally start at `0`. So your first event is actually at index 0, which is equal to `10` here.